# using gpg2 from xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server-2008, encryption, command-line, gnupg, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to use gpg2 directly from sql to encrypt a xml file that I will be sending to an outside vendor.  I can create the xml file and ftp without errors, but I am running into an issue when trying to use the gpg2 commands to encrypt the file.

I have a stored procedure that echo's commands into a .txt file and then I execute the file with xp_cmdshell.  I designed it this way so that I could create the command dynamically depending on what the file name is that you wish to encrypt.

This is the command that I am writing to the text file so that I can execute it.  This command works fine when calling from the command line on the SQL box, but it does not work within xp_cmdshell.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2" --recipient FTPUser --output C:\FTP\Outgoing\test.gpg --batch --encrypt C:\FTP\Outgoing\SomeFile.xml`

Here are the messages:

> gpg: FTPUser: skipped: No public key gpg:
>
> C:\FTP\Outgoing\SomeFile.xml: encryption failed: No public key

The gpg4win(2.2.5) program is installed directly on my SQL 2008R2 box and I have gone through the process of generating keys, and then signing them using the FTPUser account.  I was able to get the messages dumped into a temp table while executing the xp_cmdshell command in SQL.  The results are the two messages above.

Is there another gpg2 command that I need to be using when calling from SQL?  I have tried searching the interwebs, but it has proved futile.

Comment: Just guessing, maybe when executed with `xp_cmdshell` it can't reach required environment variables. Check manual what environment variables GPG2 needs (like PATH or so on) and provide them `SET name=...` before executing script.

Comment: Run `SET | more` from command line and cmdshell and compare

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.  We have a separate windows account that runs our SQL Server service.  Since that account was the one that was initiating the command, I had to make sure that I set up the keys on the db server under that account.  When I first set it up, I did it under the administrator account.  Since that is not the same account that xp_cmdshell was using to initiate the command, it could not find the public key under the account.  After adding the keys to the proper account, everything functioned properly.